# Class Redefine not working

Tags: byte-buddy

SO I am trying to redefine a class. I have a class named folder.  In OSGi (using Felix) I have a new Folder class with the same methods but some additional logging.

I am trying to take the Folder Class from Felix and redefine the main Folder class on the main classloader

I do have the agent set on startup.

```
new ByteBuddy()
                        .redefine(Class.forName(classToOverride.trim()), ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.of(felixClassLoader))
                        .name(classToOverride.trim())
                        .make()                            .load(contextClassLoader);
```

I have tried different strategies in the load method.

Without any strategies I get the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot inject already loaded type: class com.dotmarketing.portlets.folders.model.Folder
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection.inject(ClassInjector.java:187) ~[byte-buddy-1.6.12.jar:?]
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default$InjectionDispatcher.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:187) ~[byte-buddy-1.6.12.jar:?]
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:120) ~[byte-buddy-1.6.12.jar:?]
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:79) ~[byte-buddy-1.6.12.jar:?]
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:4376) ~[byte-buddy-1.6.12.jar:?]
at com.dotmarketing.osgi.GenericBundleActivator.publishBundleServices(GenericBundleActivator.java:177) ~[dotcms_4.1.0_563a5c3.jar:?]
```

With ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent  I get no error but doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

On a JVM, you cannot simply redefine an already loaded class. You can only redefine a class using a Java agent where Byte Buddy supplies the `AgentBuilder` API which you can use. Note that it is only possible to change the content of methods but not a class's layout. You probably want to have a look at the `Advice` API to do so.

Comment: Mean that is not possible to change the fields (class layout) using AgentBuilder API or both AgentBuilder and Advice, right?

Comment: It is not possible using any tool.

Comment: I thought your stackoverflow's mention if only if some Java Spec is passing? Which one it is?